# Socket.Connect Throws and Error I can't catch

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I apologize if this has been answered on SO. I looked but didn't find it. My situation is my customer can connect to their TCP server either by being on the local network, or coming in remotely via a Verizon modem. (I am using .NET 3.5 - C#)

When I connect from either of those, things are fine. But what if I am accidentally on the "wrong" network (ex: I am at Starbucks and logged onto their wireless network. I forget, thinking I am on the Verizon card, so, now I try to log in) The server refuses the connection. Fine. But my Try/Catch is not catching anything... it simply exits the routine (if I am calling it through threadpool) or it hangs if I call it directly.

Here is the code (it fails on: m_clientSocket.Connect(ipEnd) ):

```
tcpConnectionObject passedTCPObject = (tcpConnectionObject) obj;
if (checkNetStat(passedTCPObject) == false)
{
     updateStatus(false);
     return;
}

try
{
     m_clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
     IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(passedTCPObject.ipString);
     int iPortNo = System.Convert.ToInt16(passedTCPObject.portString);
     IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, iPortNo);

     m_clientSocket.Connect(ipEnd);
     if (m_clientSocket.Connected)
     {
          updateStatus(true);
          //Wait for data asynchronously 
          WaitForData();
     }
}
catch (SocketException e)
{
     updateStatus(false);
     return;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     updateStatus(false);
     return;
}

updateStatus(true);
return ;
```

I call this from a Winform using the threadpool:

```
tcpConnectionObject passObject = new tcpConnectionObject(serverIP, serverPORT);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SRVR_CONNECT.connectToTCP), passObject);
```

This is called in the form's SHOW() method. When I do it like this, my form shows, but the status is never changed (which it should be by any result) If I put a debugger on it, and start stepping through the execution, I get to the Socket.Connect() and the debugger simply exits the mthod, and my form shows. I never hit any of my catches.

I have tried every error that Socket can generate, but it never catches anything. When I run my debugger, as soon as I hit that line, it exits my method, but there is no error that is catch-able.

Comment: Based on it hanging if you call it directly I question why you htink that it exits the background thread without notification. I would assume the background thread is also hanging

Comment: Do you have the debugger set to stop when an exception is thrown (not just unhandled)?

Comment: @IgbyLargeman suggested to check what I was thinking.  If you step through, it doesn't step into the exception?

Comment: Nope -- never gets to the exception. Let me edit with more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really are waiting asynchronously (as you state in your comment), then you may be exiting the try/catch block before you actually get the exception.

Comment: Except it never reaches that line (that I can see) When I step through in the debugger, it simply exits the method when I hit the connect. Unless the debugger is confused by the pool threading things...

Comment: If you're doing anything async you'll have multiple threads; which are hard to trace through.  can you verify what you're doing in WaitForData and whether it's "Wait for data asynchronously"?

Comment: Peter, I am going to accept your answer, because I think you are more or less right... I have a more complete answer, but your sanity check turned me on to the right path...

Comment: Meh... I tried to post the code that works, but SO won't let me for 7 more hours... It sucks being a Noob... anyway, short version is that I changed it to a BeginConnect method, and set a timeout interval, which worked. (If I can remember to come back in 8 hours, I'll post the code)

Answer (score 0):

It exits your method because you have a return statement inside of your catch block. You are telling it to return explicitly.

Comment: Yes, but I put a breakpoint on every return, and none of them are hit.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think Peter was on the right track. it seems like the debugger was simply skipping over my Connect line and moving on to the next line while waiting for the Socket.Connect() to finish (if that makes sense?)

Here's a change in the code that works... I move the packet creation, and the callback definition out of "WaitForData" and use the beginConnect method instead. Then I can set a timeout, which lets me know it fails -- so the code is changed to this:

```
    try
       {
           m_clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
           // Cet the remote IP address
           IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(passedTCPObject.ipString);
           int iPortNo = System.Convert.ToInt16(passedTCPObject.portString);
           // Create the end point 
           ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, iPortNo);

           Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
           SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
           if (m_pfnCallBack == null)
           {
               m_pfnCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
           }
           // Give It 5 Seconds to connect
           IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginConnect(ipEnd, m_pfnCallBack, theSocPkt);
           bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000, true);

           if (!success)
           {
               socket.Close();
               throw new ApplicationException("Server Refused Connection");
           }
           // Success
           updateStatus(true);
       }
       catch (SocketException e)
       {
           updateStatus(false);
           return;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           updateStatus(false);
           return;
       }
```